# Exclude specific file from sourceSets

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

Working with android flavors, I'm trying to inherit a flavor from another and to override a class in the parent one. Everything looks and works perfectly except that the target class shows up as duplicated. My guess is there's a way to exclude the class on the parent flavor from sourceSets like:

```
sourceSets {
    benchmark {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/offline/java', 'src/benchmark/java']

            exclude { '**/Facade.java' in sourceSets.offline.files }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting from another flavor, use [flavor dimensions](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants)

```groovy
android {
    ...


    flavorDimensions "version", "online"


    productFlavors {    
        benchmark {
            dimension "version"
            ...
        }

        standard {
            dimension "version"
            ...
        }

        online {
            dimension "online"
            ...
        }

        offline {
            dimension "online"
            ...
        }
    }
    //optionally filter combinations you don't want
    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.flavors*.name.contains("online") && variant.flavors*.name.contains("benchmark")) {
            variant.ignore = true
        }
    }
}
```

Put one version of `facade.java` in `src\benchmark\java\com\yourcompany\namespace\facade.java`

Put the alternate version in `src\standard\java\com\yourcompany\namespace\facade.java`

Files that are always the same no matter which build flavor are left in the standard directory, `src\main\java\com\yourcompany\namespace\`